# Adding new object to CoreData with one to many relation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsnotificationcenter

I have CoreData model like this:

[image]

Parcel can have only one company, but company can have multiple parcels to deliver.

I have three companies in database preloaded. I have created table view with sections and loading data via NSFetchedResultsController.
I'm configuring it like this:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: EnityNames.PackageInfoEnityName)

        // Add Sort Descriptors
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: PackageInfoKeyPaths.Company, ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: PackageInfoKeyPaths.Company, cacheName: nil)

        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController
```

When I'm launching app on simulator I have three sections(as expected), i want to have sections as companies displayed, so I'm using relationship as section name key path:

```
number of sections 3
FedEx
UPS
DHL
```

I have created popover where I can add new entries to database to populate list with additional data. This is the code I'm using to create and save new data:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let package = 

    NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(EnityNames.PackageInfoEnityName, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! PackageInfo
            let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
            package.parcelNumber = formatter.numberFromString(parcelNumberTextField.text!) ?? 0;
            package.createdAt = NSDate()
            let company = avaialbleCompanies![companyPickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
            package.company_relation = company
            company.addPackageToCompany(package)    


            appDelegate.saveContext()
```

the companies array is passed in prepare for segue to my little popover to let user choose only companies that are inside database. After this I'm getting something strange:

```
number of sections 4
FedEx
UPS
UPS
```

Why it is adding new Section? It should just add new item to existing section!

and terrifying error:

PackageChecker[5336:281349] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo (null)

Important part can be that I'm getting this:

```
updated index path 1x0
```

and I'm using `fetchedResultsController.sections?.count` to get number of sections. 
If I restart the app on sim my newly added record is present in proper section inside list. Why it is not updating properly on runtime?

P.S. I have:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Edit:

If I remove sectionNameKeyPath: PackageInfoKeyPaths.Company - adding works perfectly. Can You help me with this sections? Maybe I'm configuring them poorly.

Comment: Have you implemented the other `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods, `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` and `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:`?

Comment: @pbasdf I added ontroller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType: because it was missing. Now list works and I can add items without error!! That is awesome. But still, instead adding new item to existing section it is creating new section after adding. When I kill my app and open it I'm getting newly added item in proper section, what I do wrong with insertion that it is adding new section instead just new element to existing one?

Comment: The only line that looks unusual is: `company.addPackageToCompany(package)`  If `addPackageToCompany` does what it says, it's superfluous: when `package.company_relation = company` is executed, CoreData automatically sets the inverse relationship.

Comment: @pbasdf I have added it later, the same without it. Should I use the same managedObjectContext as I'm using in fetch result? Should I create new one? I'm using managedObjectContext from AppDelegate.

Comment: Yes, when you set a relationship, both objects must be in the same context.  What is the value of `PackageInfoKeyPaths.Company`?

Comment: @pbasdf  I have created some constants to have everything handy: `enum EnityNames{ static let CompanyEnityName = "Company" static let PackageInfoEnityName = "PackageInfo" } enum PackageInfoKeyPaths{ static let CreatedAt = "createdAt" static let Company = "company_relation" } enum CompanyKeyPaths{ static let CompanyName = "companyName" static let PackagesInfoRelation = "packages_relation" }`

Comment: Hmmm, can't see any problem with that.

Comment: @pbasdf Ok, I would like to use accept Your comments as an answer, because crashing error is not there anymore. I'll try solve second problem on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks; I have posted an answer.  Good luck tracking down the section problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is occurring because the FRC is creating a new section, but your code does not currently create a corresponding tableView section.  If you implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method:

`controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:`

that should fix the crash.

But I'm afraid I can't see why the FRC is creating a new section.